# Grouping secrets in azure key-vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying store secrets in azure vault. I used azure sdk apis and I can successfully store/retrieve using those. I wanted to know if it's possible to categorise/group set of secrets under same tag and store them in some path.

I want to group some secrets used by one service, store them in one storage path. The same way for other services is separate storage paths. I couldn't find any way of doing that. Is that possible in azure vault?

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, this is not possible.
Also: you cannot get secrets *and their values* in a list. If you want to get a list, you'll only get a [SecretItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecrets/getsecrets#secretitem) array and you have to call GetSecret on each secret you want to get the actual value for.

You *could*, however, implement something like this yourself by defining a template for the name of the secret that incorporates the name of the thing you would like to group on. Something like this:

`$"{serviceName}-secrets-{secretName}"`

This way, you can filter the list to only hold the secrets for the service you want to get them for and get their values.